# How to use mouse to scroll through time stamp in VLC player?

Tags: mouse, vlc-media-player, scrolling

I'm listening to a mix in VLC player and I'd like to scroll forward and backward using the mouse.  I was only able to get the volume to go up and down, so I disabled that. But I want to be able to scroll through the time stamp. I used Marquee to make the timestamp appear. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me i had to write a fairly basic AutoHotkey script which when it detects VLC is running and has focus and sees me using my middle-mouse scroll wheel it then triggers the video to move forward and backward.